# Impossible to run the gunicorn because of the import error

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, centos, gunicorn

I have had a `django==2.1` project with `virualenv`. Then to solve some package problems I created another `virtualenv` for my project and activated it. However whenever I run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application` I am receiving the following problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
worker.init_process()
File "/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
self.load_wsgi()
File "/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
self.callable = self.load()
File "/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
__import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'
[2019-01-17 04:16:14 +0500] [21107] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21107)
[2019-01-17 04:16:14 +0500] [21104] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-01-17 04:16:14 +0500] [21104] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. This is my gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/uzagro_4
ExecStart=/home/root/uzagro_4/agrosenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 
unix:/home/root/uzagro_4/myproject.sock uzagro_4.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the nginx.conf file:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
server_name agros.uz www.agros.uz;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
       root /home/root/uzagro_4/;
}

location / {    
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/home/root/uzagro_4/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Your gunicorn.service file seems to start gunicorn with `uzagro_4.wsgi:application` but on the command line you're using `myproject.wsgi:application`. It would help if you could post the folder structure of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Module import error... i think it because you didn't actually start venv before running gunicon, since you are doing that directly from the service file. you can write a bash file with some commands to enable venv before starting gunicorn so it will be running inside it. Take a look at this article :

http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Regards.

Comment: I checked the link it's great. But no I activated venv before running that command. I guess gunicorn.service is pointing to the old venv.

Comment: even if you enable it youselft by hand it won't work, it should be enable by the same process who launch the server, this is why it the link he define all those operation in one program ( bash )...

Comment: Well I am new to django and its first time me hosting how i am going to do that